# PHP reports based on Json template

Tags: php, arrays, json, symfony

I am developing a system of forms built on Json data, in the form of form defitions, outputs, and then report templating. My app is based on Symfony2 and uses AWS S3 for the Json storage, but I should be able to move any generic PHP to that framework.

Basically, I need to be able to update the template json node which will then change the way that records are displayed in a page. The tough thing is that the output template will be multi level. Ie we may want to group on Name and then on Date at the next level down. The following is an example of how I might want it all to look.

**QUESTION JSON** - a definition of all questions

```
"questions": [
        {
          "id": 0,
          "question": {
            "question": "Name",
            "type": "Textbox",
          }
        },
        {
          "id": 1,
          "question": {
            "question": "Email",
            "type": "Textbox",
          }
        },
        {
          "id": 2,
          "question": {
            "question": "Date",
            "type": "DateTime",
          }
        }
]
```

**ANSWER ARRAY JSON** - one for each form filled out

```
"Questions" : [
    {
        "answer" : "john smith"
        "question" : 0
    },
    {
        "answer" : "js@abc.com"
        "question" : 1
    },
    {
         "answer" : "01/01/2015"
         "question" : 2
    }
]

"Questions" : [
        {
            "answer" : "john smith"
            "question" : 0
        },
        {
            "answer" : "js_secondemail@abc.com"
            "question" : 1
        },
        {
            "answer" : "01/01/2015"
            "question" : 2
        }
    ]
```

**OUTPUT TEMPLATE JSON** - a definition of how we want the data to be displayed

```
"outputStructure": [{
    "output": [{
        "showReport": true,
        "groupBy": 'Name'
    }]
}]
```

And that should all end up with my php page displaying the following:

```
John Smith (link)
===js@abc.com.au
===js_secondemail@abc.com.au
```

If anyone can help it will be much appreciated!